# "package ‘rhipe’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)"

Tags: r

When i try to install Rhipe in winndows "package ‘rhipe’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)". appear
Is there any other rhipe package which will install on R version 3.1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RHIPE` is not available on CRAN (yet).  Follow the instructions on the [RHIPE Install page](http://www.datadr.org/install.html).

That page has a link to the R package, which you can download and then install with

```
install.packages("rhipe_version.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Note that to get it to work there are other dependencies (Hadoop, R set up as a shared library, protocol buffers, some environment variables).

Comment: Sir I used this link I have downloaded "Rhipe_0.73.1.tar" now how I can give the location of downloaded file. because when i try to install pkg the error ('lib' is unspecified) occur @Richie Cotton

Comment: Read the output again. `"lib" is unspecified` is not an error message, just information.